# Does the srand function work over multiple translation units?

Tags: c, random, srand

If I call `srand` in my `main` function, would it also affect results in my functions in other translation units?

Comment: It will affect the executed program that is built from several translation units.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow could you post it as an answer?

Comment: I do not really understand what you are meaning. What do you mean exactly with "affect results in my functions in other translation units"? Do you call functions defined  in other TLUs in main? Could you provide an example for your thought model?

Comment: `srand` is provided by a library, and is linked with an executable (more specifically, one instance of the running executable, i.e. a process). An executable does not differentiate between the different source files/translation units. It will affect all future calls to `rand` in the executable, from whatever function calls it (`main` or otherwise). It will, however, not affect different processes. Therefore, calling `srand` in one process will not affect parent or sibling processes. It will affect children spawned subsequently.

Comment: Depends on the implementation. The Standard only mandates that the sequence of numbers generated with the same seed will be the same everytime... `return 4;` is a valid (though very low-quality) implementation of `rand()` --- [mandatory xkcd](https://xkcd.com/221/) --- if you add threads to the mix, then all bets are off!

Comment: @pmg Also [mandatory Dilbert](https://dilbert.com/strip/2001-10-25).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some small information from the source code of glibc.

`srand` is a weak alias for `__srandom`. ([Source](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/895ef79e04a953cac1493863bcae29ad85657ee1/stdlib/random.c#L216)).

`__srandom` calls `__srandom_r` ([Source](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/895ef79e04a953cac1493863bcae29ad85657ee1/stdlib/random.c#L211)).

`__srandom_r` is just updating the `struct random_data` passed to it, based on the seed.
([Source](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/895ef79e04a953cac1493863bcae29ad85657ee1/stdlib/random_r.c#L161))

`rand(void)` is just calling `__random`. ([Source](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/895ef79e04a953cac1493863bcae29ad85657ee1/stdlib/rand.c#L27)).

`__random` calls `__random_r`, passing the same structure, that was passed to `__srandom_r`. ([Source](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/895ef79e04a953cac1493863bcae29ad85657ee1/stdlib/random.c#L293)).

`__random_r` then generates a random value from the passed struct. ([Source](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/895ef79e04a953cac1493863bcae29ad85657ee1/stdlib/random_r.c#L353)).

So, to put it in a nutshell, a call to `srand` in your main-function will affect the random numbers in every other function, while your program runs, as the state is shared between all functions.

Comment: `rand` is generally not considered thread-safe nor reentrant (although it appears to be thread safe in the [glibc/random.c](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/895ef79e04a953cac1493863bcae29ad85657ee1/stdlib/random.c#L293) file that you linked above).

Comment: More generally, how glibc does it (anything) is not reliably indicative of how other C libraries do it, except to the extent that glibc conforms to standards.

Comment: @JohnBollinger You are right, but I assumed, people will know, that it will depend on the library and the standard conformance how `rand`/`srand` is implemented. Furthermore I used glibc, as it is found quite often on linux-systems

Comment: @JCWasmx86, a lot of people will see this answer who *don't* know or understand that.  Moreover, the OP did not specify a particular implementation, much less a glibc-based one in particular.  Inasmuch as you *do* know that glibc details are not indicative of other implementations' details, then, it is unclear to me why you think this is responsive to the OP's question at all.

Answer (score 1):

C translation units bound the scope for some *identifiers* that are declared within, but not for any actual functions or objects belonging to a program.  Thus, program state cannot be TU-specific, in the sense that it varies for different TUs.

Specifically, then, in any particular thread of a program exercising only defined behaviors, the random number seed set via `srand()` cannot appear differently to code in one TU than it would do at the same time to code in a different TU.